# DataBinding error after rebuild

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my app I am using the DataBinding util

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Everything works fine until I rebuild my project, then I get following error meassages:

several of these:

> error:(12, 40) error: cannot find symbol class MyClassNameBinding

and a big one:

> error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
>
> ****/ data binding error ****
>
> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:src' with parameter type android.graphics.drawable.Drawable on android.widget.ImageView.
>     file:[myPath]\layer_edit_list_item.xml
>     loc:25:27 - 25:209
>
> ****\ data binding error ****
>     ****/ data binding error ****
>
> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.ImageButton.
>     file:[myPath]\composition_list_item.xml
>     loc:25:31 - 25:73
>
> ****\ data binding error ****
>     ****/ data binding error ****
>
> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.LinearLayout.
>     file:[myPath]\line_list_item.xml
>     loc:14:27 - 14:59
>
> ****\ data binding error ****
>     ****/ data binding error ****
>
> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.LinearLayout.
>     file:[myPath]\content.xml
>     loc:50:43 - 50:83
>
> ****\ data binding error ****
>     ****/ data binding error ****
>
> msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type lambda on android.widget.LinearLayout.
>     file:[myPath]\search_list_item.xml
>     loc:14:27 - 14:65
>
> ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: I have face with this problem.
So my solution is Change to Project View-> Remove .Gradle and .idea folder -> Rebuild project -> Done

Comment: @BhavikMakwana It worked! Thank you so much! Post as an answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced with this problem. So my solution is Change to Project View-> Remove .Gradle and .idea folder -> Rebuild project -> Done

Answer (score 0):

@Jan The mentioned error would happen if you forget to add **data** tag in your corresponding layout file or if you add wrong variable by using model class in view . so please you make sure everything is correctely added in the layout xml file. and rebuild again. if it still persists, then try to invalidate/restart cache,

Comment: As I said - everything worked fine until I hit rebuild. The answer from Bhavik Makawana worked for me